# Select Control - jQuery Show options that have not been previously selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would appreciate if you will help me with the next problem I have. The following view shows a table with a `button` that dynamically adds new rows to the table and each row is predefined with a `select` type control.
[image]

I use [Select2](https://select2.org/) to give it the style that can see the `select`

My question is the following, how can I get that every time I add a new row to the table, when opening the `select`, just show me the `options` that have not been previously selected.I use jQuery.
Thank you very much in advance

**EDIT 1**
What I tried:

```
$(document).on('select2:opening', 'select[name^="table2"]', function() {

            let input = $(this);

            let initialOptions = [];

            let selectedOptions = [];

            $(input.find('option').each(function(id, option) {
                initialOptions.push(option);
            }));

            $('select[name^="table2"] option:selected').each(function() {
                selectedOptions.push($(this).val());
            });

            initialOptions.splice($.inArray(selectedOptions, initialOptions), 1 );
        });
```

**EDIT 2**

Guys, nothing you've commented on has worked, it's frustrating, so far I only have 2 array of objects:

```
$(document).on('select2:opening', 'select[name^="table2"]', function() {

            let input = $(this);

            let initialOptions = [];

            let selectedOptions = [];

            $(input.find('option').each(function() {
                initialOptions.push($(this));
            }));

            $('select[name^="table2"] option:selected').each(function() {
                selectedOptions.push($(this));
            });

            console.log(initialOptions);
            console.log(selectedOptions);
        });
```

the console returns me these 2 arrays:

```
Array(24) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]

Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

expanded:

```
24) […]
​
0: Object [ option
 ]
​
1: Object [ option
 ]
​
2: Object [ option
 ]
​
3: Object [ option
 ]
​
4: Object [ option
 ]
​
5: Object [ option
 ]
​
6: Object [ option
 ]
​
7: Object [ option
 ]
​
8: Object [ option
 ]
​
9: Object [ option
 ]
​
10: Object [ option
 ]
​
11: Object [ option ]
```

and the second

```
(3) […]
​
0: Object [ option
 ]
​
1: Object [ option
 ]
​
2: Object [ option
 ]
​
length: 3
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

I need to remove from the first array all the objects that are in the second, except one that meets the condition that the value is equal to a certain number.

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: @NegiRox Sorry, I can't .. please see EDIT 2

Comment: see the answer it may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can have an array of options e.g.

```
var optionsArray = [option1, option2,..... and so on]
```

Upon each add new row click, you need to create a clone of this array which should be compared (using a loop)  with selected options in other rows (if exist) and values that has previously been selected should be removed using jquery array.splice()e.g.

```
clonedArray.splice( $.inArray(selectedVal, clonedArray), 1 );
```

Then, this filtered array should be used to populate the dropdown.

> **Edit** (to remove selected array from Initial Array)

```
var initialArray =  [1,2,3,4,5]
var selectedArray = [3,5]
var clonedArray = initialArray
for(var i=0; i<selectedArray.length;i++) {
clonedArray.splice($.inArray(selectedArray[i], clonedArray), 1)

}
//Cloned array is now filtered array
```

what the above code will do is to find the index of every selectedArray item using `$.inArray()` function and use that index as parameter to `splice()` function

Comment: if table is created form json then just push the element to the array and refresh. Array.push(element object)

Comment: Please check EDIT 2

Comment: why are you pushing parent control in arrays. you just need to push option text.e.g.$(this).text()

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider I'm sorry, I didn't realize, I was trying that way when uploading the code

Comment: this option object in your 'edit2' should give you `text` and `value` property. you need to push `text` in arrays and create resultant array

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by manupilating datasource below code is just an idea how to implement it you can modify this with your own requirement.

```js
var data = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'enhancement'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'bug'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'duplicate'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'invalid'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: 'wontfix'
    }
];
var selectedValue=[];
var select="select_";
var counter=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#AddNew").on('click',function(){
       var dataSource=[];
       for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
           var name=data[i].text;
           if($.inArray(name,selectedValue)==-1){
              dataSource.push(data[i]);
           }
       }
      var config={
        data: dataSource
      } 
      var id=select+counter;
      var selectcontrol=$("<select/>",{id:id});
      selectcontrol.on('change',function(){
          var selvalue=$(this)[0].selectedOptions[0].label;
          
          if($.inArray(selvalue,selectedValue)==-1){
              selectedValue.push(selvalue)
           }
          $(this).attr("disabled",true)
      })
      $("#select2Div").append(selectcontrol);
      $("#"+id).select2(config);
      counter++;
   })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>


<br/>
<input type='button' id='AddNew' value='Add New'/>
<div id='select2Div'></div>
```